# Changing SMS or Mobile Phone Number Associated with Google App Engine Account

Tags: google-app-engine

I just recently picked up a new number and cell phone plan, and would like to change the SMS or mobile phone number associated with my Google App Engine account, since the number that I initially used to register with was associated with some free texting service online.  Alternatively, I would like to completely purge App Engine from my Google account, so that I can at least reregister for App Engine with my new number.

How can I go about enacting these changes?  Who do I turn to for assistance with these issues?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try filling out the [SMS issues form](https://appengine.google.com/waitlist/sms_issues) and describing your issue in the comments section. If you're unable to see the form, a reply to [this pinned Google Groups post about signup issues](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/google-appengine/kk7xwZK26Wk/discussion) may receive some attention.